# This Serverless Function has timed out

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I create a chat app using mern stack. After deploy server in vercel. but it is not work. there is a error in vercel log.

`Legacy server listening... MongoServerError: bad auth : authentication failed at Connection.onMessage (/var/task/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:207:30) at MessageStream.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:60:60) at MessageStream.emit (node:events:513:28) at processIncomingData (/var/task/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:132:20) at MessageStream._write (/var/task/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:33:9) at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12) at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:333:10) at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:337:10) at TLSSocket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:766:22) at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28) { ok: 0, code: 8000, codeName: 'AtlasError', connectionGeneration: 0, [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(2) { 'HandshakeError', 'ResetPool' } }`

I use mogoose express js

Answer (score 0):

Check your MongoDB IP address Whitelist if you use MongoDB atlas.
Refer to this:
[https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/mongodb-atlas-login-ip-whitelisting/#:~:text=To%20whitelist%20multiple%20IP%20addresses,Whitelist%20Entry%2C%20then%20click%20Confirm.](https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/mongodb-atlas-login-ip-whitelisting/#:%7E:text=To%20whitelist%20multiple%20IP%20addresses,Whitelist%20Entry%2C%20then%20click%20Confirm.)

Answer (score 0):

You maybe forgot to add the ip adress for mongodb access.

1.Got to mongodb

2.Click Network Access

3.Add Ip Adress

4.Click ALLOW ACCESS FROM ANYWHERE

Now you should see in the List field an Ip adress with `0.0.0.0/0`

Comment: This can be dangerous because makes your database accessible from everywhere.

Comment: Yes you're right, but Vercel uses dynamic IP addresses so we have to do it. Currently I am looking for alternatives for Ip adress. Maybe the link can help you https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/partner-integrations/vercel/

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Unfortunately, this is apparently the only way.